# What is being deprecated in Android M?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I know `getResources()` is being deprecated. So before where we could do things like:

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_color)
getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector_color_list)
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)
```

We now have to do like this:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary_color)
ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(), R.color.selector_color_list)
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon)
```

And I know there is mention of [Deprecated HTTP Classes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#http)

My questions is is there anything being deprecated in the upcoming release that we should be aware of?.

Comment: See [API Differences](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html). Select the "Removals" filter on the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [API Diff](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html) contains a [full list of all removals](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/alldiffs_index_removals.html):

Although the best place to read in summary about the major changes is in the [Behavior Changes documentation](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html)

> - AbstractHttpParams
> - ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION
> - ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER
> - ACCESSIBILITY_FEATURES
> - ACCOUNTS
> - addSearchUrl (ContentResolver, String)
> - AFFECTS_BATTERY
> - AndroidHttpClient
> - APP_INFO
> - APPEND_FOR_LAST_AUDIBLE
> - ArrayMap (ArrayMap) constructor
> - AUDIO_SETTINGS
> - AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS
> - BasicEofSensorWatcher
> - BasicHttpParams
> - BasicManagedEntity
> - BatteryManager () constructor
> - BLUETOOTH_NETWORK
> - BOOKMARKS
> - BOOKMARKS_URI
> - BRICK
> - Browser.BookmarkColumns
> - Browser.SearchColumns
> - canClearHistory (ContentResolver)
> - ceil (float)
> - CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA
> - clearHistory (ContentResolver)
> - clearSearches (ContentResolver)
> - ClientConnectionManager
> - ClientConnectionManagerFactory
> - ClientConnectionOperator
> - ClientConnectionRequest
> - ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy
> - ConnectionPoolTimeoutException
> - ConnectionReleaseTrigger
> - ContactsContract.Contacts.StreamItems
> - ContactsContract.RawContacts.StreamItems
> - ContactsContract.StreamItemPhotos
> - ContactsContract.StreamItemPhotosColumns
> - ContactsContract.StreamItems
> - ContactsContract.StreamItems.StreamItemPhotos
> - ContactsContract.StreamItemsColumns
> - CoreProtocolPNames
> - cos (float)
> - COST_MONEY
> - createFromPdu (byte[])
> - createFromXml (Resources, XmlPullParser)
> - DefaultedHttpParams
> - deleteFromHistory (ContentResolver, String)
> - deleteHistoryTimeFrame (ContentResolver, long, long)
> - DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS
> - DEVICE_ALARMS
> - DEVICE_POWER
> - DISPLAY
> - EofSensorInputStream
> - EofSensorWatcher
> - execute ()
> - exp (float)
> - floor (float)
> - FORCE_BACK
> - GET_TOP_ACTIVITY_INFO
> - getAllBookmarks (ContentResolver)
> - getAllVisitedUrls (ContentResolver)
> - getColor (int)
> - getColorStateList (int)
> - getHttpSocketFactory (int, SSLSessionCache)
> - HARDWARE_CONTROLS
> - HARDWARE_TEST
> - HISTORY_PROJECTION
> - HISTORY_PROJECTION_BOOKMARK_INDEX
> - HISTORY_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX
> - HISTORY_PROJECTION_FAVICON_INDEX 
>     HISTORY_PROJECTION_ID_INDEX
> - HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX
> - HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX
> - HISTORY_PROJECTION_VISITS_INDEX
> - HttpAbstractParamBean
> - HttpConnectionParamBean
> - HttpHostConnectException
> - HttpProtocolParamBean
> - HttpProtocolParams
> - hypot (float, float)
> - INJECT_EVENTS
> - INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW
> - MANAGE_ACCOUNTS
> - MANAGE_APP_TOKENS
> - ManagedClientConnection
> - mCurrentRowID
> - MESSAGES
> - mRowIdColumnIndex
> - MultihomePlainSocketFactory
> - mUpdatedRows
> - NETWORK
> - onAttach (Activity)
> - onReceivedError (WebView, int, String, String)
> - onSendDataSms (byte[], int, String, int, ResultCallback)
> - onSendMultipartTextSms (List, int, String, ResultCallback)
> - onSendTextSms (String, int, String, ResultCallback)
> - OperatedClientConnection
> - org.apache.commons.logging
> - org.apache.http
> - org.apache.http.auth
> - org.apache.http.auth.params
> - org.apache.http.client
> - org.apache.http.client.entity
> - org.apache.http.client.methods
> - org.apache.http.client.params
> - org.apache.http.client.protocol
> - org.apache.http.client.utils
> - org.apache.http.conn.params
> - org.apache.http.conn.routing
> - org.apache.http.conn.util
> - org.apache.http.cookie
> - org.apache.http.cookie.params
> - org.apache.http.entity
> - org.apache.http.impl
> - org.apache.http.impl.auth
> - org.apache.http.impl.client
> - org.apache.http.impl.conn
> - org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm
> - org.apache.http.impl.cookie
> - org.apache.http.impl.entity
> - org.apache.http.impl.io
> - org.apache.http.io
> - org.apache.http.message
> - org.apache.http.protocol
> - org.apache.http.util
> - PERSONAL_INFO
> - PHONE_CALLS
> - PlainSocketFactory
> - play (Context, Uri, boolean, int)
> - pow (float, float)
> - READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
> - READ_PROFILE
> - READ_SOCIAL_STREAM
> - READ_USER_DICTIONARY
> - RecoverySystem () constructor
> - requestAllIcons (ContentResolver, String, IconListener)
> - REQUESTED_PERMISSION_REQUIRED
> - saveBookmark (Context, String, String)
> - Scheme
> - SchemeRegistry
> - SCREENLOCK
> - SEARCHES_PROJECTION
> - SEARCHES_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX
> - SEARCHES_PROJECTION_SEARCH_INDEX
> - SEARCHES_URI
> - SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER
> - SET_ORIENTATION
> - SET_POINTER_SPEED
> - setColorFilter
>
>   - type  (ColorFilter) in android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable
>   - type  (ColorFilter) in android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable
>   - type  (ColorFilter) in android.graphics.drawable.RotateDrawable
>   - type  (ColorFilter) in android.graphics.drawable.ScaleDrawable
> - setLatestEventInfo (Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, PendingIntent)
> - sin (float)
> - SOCIAL_INFO
> - sqrt (float)
> - startSession (Bundle)
> - STATUS_BAR
> - SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ
> - SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_WRITE
> - SYNC_SETTINGS
> - SYSTEM_CLOCK
> - SYSTEM_TOOLS
> - TRUNCATE_HISTORY_PROJECTION
> - TRUNCATE_HISTORY_PROJECTION_ID_INDEX
> - TRUNCATE_N_OLDEST
> - truncateHistory (ContentResolver)
> - updateVisitedHistory (ContentResolver, String, boolean)
> - USE_CREDENTIALS
> - USER_DICTIONARY
> - VOICEMAIL
> - VOLUME_ALARM
> - VOLUME_BLUETOOTH_SCO
> - VOLUME_MUSIC
> - VOLUME_NOTIFICATION
> - VOLUME_RING
> - VOLUME_SETTINGS
> - VOLUME_SYSTEM
> - VOLUME_VOICE
> - WALLPAPER
> - WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
> - WRITE_PROFILE
> - WRITE_SMS
> - WRITE_SOCIAL_STREAM
> - WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY
>
>   - in  android.Manifest.permission
>   - in  android.Manifest.permission_group